# MySQL Merge 3 Tables into 1

Tags: php, mysql, search, join

I am creating a search box in PHP and using MySQL as the database but when searching there are 3 tables, Colours, Products and Categories, these all have an ID number and can be linked. I have tried to use INNER JOIN, LEFT, RIGHT, everywhere but no luck, the query will sometimes work, spit out multiple items. So I am looking at creating a one-table-fits-all scenario where all the table field names will be in one and I can easily query that table. I have manually created the table but is there anyway of coping the data from the 3 tables into that main one? I do not mind doing it separately if it is a query that only handles one table but I would love not to have to manually type all the data as there is 600+ rows.

Here is the code I am currently trying to use:

```
SELECT
    categories.Product_Type, items_colors.ColourImageurl,
    items_list.description,  items_list.Description2,
    items_list.title, items_list.id, categories.title AS title2,
    items_colors.itemID, Colour Name
FROM items_list
    LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.Product_Type = items_list.CatID
    LEFT JOIN items_colors ON items_list.id = items_colors.itemID
WHERE items_list.visible = 1 AND
    Colour Name LIKE '%".$search."%'
```

Categories defines what type of product you are selecting, items_list has a list of all the sub category names and item_colors has a list of all the colour names that link to the items_list products. When I use this query it outputs 4 copies of one item and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Example of SQL being used please.

Comment: You should look at UNION. that's what helps here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: @Flukey , Here is the code I am trying to use, but it shows copies of the same items at least 4 times:


SELECT categories.Product_Type, items_colors.ColourImageurl, items_list.description, items_list.Description2, items_list.title, items_list.id, categories.title AS title2, items_colors.itemID,  `Colour Name` 
FROM items_list
LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.Product_Type = items_list.CatID
LEFT JOIN items_colors ON items_list.id = items_colors.itemID
WHERE items_list.visible = 1 AND `Colour Name` LIKE '%".$search."%'"

Comment: @AzzerB You can edit your post to add the query there. It will probably help you getting more accurate responses

Comment: One thing I've found is that if you can't figure out the query, just do multiple queries then sort it out with code (assuming you're comfortable with the server-side language you are using).

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data from a query, you can use "create table as select" statement to create the new table, with data from old tables.

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    [(create_definition,...)]
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
    select_statement
```

check here for more info : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: I'm not getting data from a query as such, I want to mirror 3 tables and merge them into one, permanently. The table will not be updated very much so this is perfect for me..